# Insert code source with listings and problem with special french characters

Tags: listings, babel, babel-french

I'm having a problem using listings. Everything works fine until I want to insert special French characters such as é or è. From that moment on, I get an error message. However, I had specified in my document header \usepackage[french]{babel} and then \usepackage{listings}. I've inverted the two too, but it doesn't work.
What solutions do I have left?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: How you inserting those characters?

Comment: Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8 , but without a MWE hard to test